# How to add names to rows and columns in existing R matrices

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I'm working on R matrices and i am unable to add names to rows (titles) and columns(region) with this set of problem. My data set is as follows-

- Box office sales

```r
terminator_1 <- c(66.1, 317.6, 657.2)
terminator_2 <- c(54.7, 261.9, 616.9)
terminator_3 <- c(45.6, 249.5, 547.1)
```

- Vectors that I have used for naming region and titles are

```r
region <- c("UK", "US", "Other")
titles <- c("terminator_1", "terminator_2", "terminator_3")
```

I want to be able to add names to the matrix's rows (titles) and columns (region)

The am trying to get an o/p like the following-

```
    terminator_1 terminator_2 terminator_3
  US 66.1 54.7 45.6

  UK 317.2 261.9 249.5

  Other 657.2 616.9 547.1
```

Comment: You might prefer using a `data.frame` instead of a matrix.  See `help(data.frame)`.

Comment: it's an assignment that needs to be done without using data frames

Comment: @sboysel There's nothing wrong with using a `matrix`. Why use a `data.frame`? There are no mixed type columns. `matrix` operations are also generally faster than `data.frame` ops.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, I do see your point.  I suggested a `data.frame` since the data  is small and I personally find the code such as `data.frame(t_1, t_2, t_3, row.names = c("UK", "US", "Other"))` slightly more readable.  Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
mat <- cbind(sapply(ls()[grep("terminator", ls())], get))
rownames(mat) <- region
#      terminator_1 terminator_2 terminator_3
#UK            66.1         54.7         45.6
#US           317.6        261.9        249.5
#Other        657.2        616.9        547.1
```

Explanation: We use `get` to column-bind all `numeric` vectors that contain the string `"terminator"` from the current environment. Then use `rownames` to set the row names of the `matrix`.

---

Or much cleaner & more succinct using `mget` (thanks to @d.b)

```
mat <- do.call(cbind, mget(titles))    
rownames(mat) <- region
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(mget(titles), setNames, region)
#      terminator_1 terminator_2 terminator_3
#UK            66.1         54.7         45.6
#US           317.6        261.9        249.5
#Other        657.2        616.9        547.1
```